# How to draw dotted lines with pointed ends over rows and columns over a table taking input range of cell values

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to draw dotted lines as Rules which can be for rows or columns.
There can be multiple rules. I have a table which is rendered using AngularJs.
The table data looks like this [image: table]

fiddle for same -  [table fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq7Lra0r/3/) .

What I want to do is for rows - e.g. - if user inputs `BJ11:BJ13 OR BJ14:BJ16` as row rules then it should look like this on the left hand side of the table pointing the same given rules value-
[image]

So for columns in same way if user inputs `BJ12:BL12 OR BK14:BN14` as column rules then it should look like this above the table pointing the same given rules value -[image]

How can I achieve the same in angular as the rules will be saved, modified.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is a very broad question. You're not asking about a specific problem, you're asking for someone to come up with the entire solution. Perhaps you want to break down your problem and ask about the element(s) you're stuck on?

Comment: @fubar More specifically i am stuck with how can i draw those rules lines.I have no idea how to began with.

Comment: You could use `div` elements with `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, positioned relatively to the table. If the column widths and row heights are consistent, you can offset the `div` position and calculate the length accordingly.

Comment: Something like this perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/k7k2pbdL/3/ But having done this, I'd suggest calculating and applying styles inline based on the size of your table.

Comment: @fubar sorry for the late response..your suggestion helped me out.